# Make an ad appear every 5 minutes?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, session-cookies

Below is code I'm using to make an ad appear once a day. I want to switch it to appear once every 5 minutes. I thought changing the value of 1 in the script to 0.004 (if 1 = a day, .004 = about 5 minutes), but it doesn't seem to be working properly. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

```
<style>
    #donationad {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 40px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 150px;
        z-index: 999;
        display: none;
    }

    #donationad.hide {
        display: none;
    }

    .closebutton {
        position: relative;
        top: 20px;
        left: 230px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .closebutton img {
        width: 30px;
        height: auto;
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.closebutton').click(function() {
            $("#donationad").toggleClass("hide");
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="donationad">
    <div class="closebutton"> <img src="http://www.dbknews.com/pb/resources/assets/img/modal_close_button.png"> </div>
    <a href="http://dbknews.com/donate"> <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/wapopartners.com/dbknews-wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/24020402/DBK-Donate250x150.jpg"> </a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cookie = document.cookie;
    if (cookie.indexOf('visited=', 0) == -1) {
        var expiration = new Date();
        expiration.setDate(expiration.getDate() + 1);
        document.cookie = 'visited=1;expires=' + expiration + ';path=/';
        var element = document.getElementById('donationad');
        element.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You want a new ad every five minutes while the user visits the site or you want a new ad every five minutes regardless. being that every five minutes everyone sees the exact same ad at given time x

Comment: Every 5 minutes once the user sees it. So, I essentially want the user to get a cookie that expires in five minutes. Once it expires, the ad will be visible again and a new cookie will be attached.

Sorry, hopefully that's a bit more clear.

Comment: Kinda two fold here. If you want the expiration to control it when a reload occurs then mr.rogers idea works on reload. But it won't work if they just sit on the page. You will need to wrap your code to check the cookie in a [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) and just use the equivalent of 5 mins in increment of 1000 seconds.

Comment: Also if you wanted to catch coders like ourselves who may be doing F12 just check if the element exists still so you have no errors and then add if it it doesn't. You can look up how to do that if you're concerned, but that is a little bit more work.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm not too worried about them sitting on the page, so I'm mainly looking for it to work on reload. I really appreciate all of the information. I'm really rusty when it comes to javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date.setDate sets the day of the month, not the "date". Confusing? Yes.

What you want is something different entirely.

```
document.cookie = 'visited=1;max-age=300;path=/';
// 300 is 5 minutes in seconds
```

This creates a cookie that can only live 5 minutes and you don't need to deal with date at all. You will lose old versions of IE, which will treat the cookie as temporary.

Comment: Quick question: updated the line of code, and now the ad just continues to appear without disappearing. Am I missing something?

Also, I'll totally mark it as answered once the 5 minute point is reached.

Comment: So the ad is still visible on refresh, is what you're saying?

Comment: Yup, exactly. I'm thinking I might need to change this: if (cookie.indexOf('visited=', 0) == -1)

Comment: No, that's fine. If you check document.cookies on the changed code, it isn't even saving the visited cookie. So something else is wrong.

Comment: wrap the javascript in document.ready as well. this will insure that that everything is loaded after the rest of everything is (even though it is at bottom might load faster than the div itself). then also add a display=none in style for the div in question that should be hidden unless they haven't visted.

Comment: All my research has shown that the expiration must be for a different date (day) in the future. Unless someone can correct, it doesn't appear like you can set a cookie that's only five minutes in the future. Unless five minutes from now happens to be tomorrow.

Comment: Check my updated answered, that should do what you want.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Can't tell you how much I appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome. You can test by setting max-age to a low value like 5 (seconds).